# Simple injector MVC ActionFilter dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have been trying to follow through this [article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98) on how to inject my dependencies into my custom `LogActionFilter` but I can't lie. I'm thoroughly confused and require some help with reaching the finishing line(I.E injecting my dependencies into my custom action filter and also with the explanation of how it is done. So far I have this:

IActionFilter:

```
public interface IActionFilter<TAttribute> where TAttribute : Attribute {
    void OnActionExecuting(TAttribute attribute, ActionExecutingContext context);
}
```

LogActionDecorator:

```
public class LogActionDecorator<TAttribute> : IActionFilter<TAttribute> 
    where TAttribute : Attribute {
    private readonly IActionFilter<TAttribute> _decoratee;
    private readonly IAccountManagementManager _iAccountManagementManager;

    public LogActionDecorator(
        IActionFilter<TAttribute> decoratee, 
        IAccountManagementManager iAccountManagementManager) {
        this._decoratee = decoratee;
        this._iAccountManagementManager = iAccountManagementManager;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(TAttribute attribute, ActionExecutingContext context) {
        this._decoratee.OnActionExecuting(attribute, context);
    }
}
```

ActionFilterDispatcher:

```
public class ActionFilterDispatcher : IActionFilter {
    private readonly Func<Type, IEnumerable> _container;

    public ActionFilterDispatcher(Func<Type, IEnumerable> container) {
        this._container = container;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) { }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
        var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor;
        var attributes = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .Concat(descriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true))
            .Cast<Attribute>();

        foreach (var attribute in attributes) {
            Type filterType = typeof(IActionFilter<>)
                .MakeGenericType(attribute.GetType());
            IEnumerable filters = this._container.Invoke(filterType);

            foreach (dynamic actionFilter in filters) {
                actionFilter.OnActionExecuting((dynamic)attribute, context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LogActionFiter:

```
public class LogActionFilter : IActionFilter<ActionFilterAttribute> {
    private readonly IAccountManagementManager _iAccountManagementManager;
    public LogActionFilter(IAccountManagementManager iAccountManagementManager) {
        _iAccountManagementManager = iAccountManagementManager;
    }
    public void OnActionExecuting(
        ActionFilterAttribute attribute, ActionExecutingContext context) {
        var fg = _iAccountManagementManager.ReturnApplicationIDAsync();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[LogActionFilter] //Build error LogActionFilter is not an attribute class
public class AccountManagementController : Controller {

    public async Task<ActionResult> EndImpersonation() {
      //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with injecting my dependencies into my custom action filter and also explain how this is done? DI is sometimes really hard to understand

Comment: I think the error you are making is caused by not fully understanding what it is the article tries to achieve. The idea is to have passive (code-less) attributes backed with fully functional components. The controller should depend on the attribute, not the component.

Comment: Hi Steven, I was hoping you'd reply haha. You're right, yesterday was a long day and I didn't really understand how the article fit together. I've taken another look and re-worked my code and got it to work. I believe I understand how the code fits together but not the "why" I need to do this for DI for Attributes. I'm going to re-read your article to try get a better understanding. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mark your controller with `ActionFilterAttribute`, instead of `LogActionFilter`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and answer. They both helped, I have added an answer with my code but you told me how to get there so I have selected this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

IActionFilter:

```
/// <summary>
/// My ActionFilter which takes an Attribute
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TAttribute">The attribute type(E.g ActionFilterAttribute)</typeparam>
public interface IActionFilter<TAttribute> where TAttribute : Attribute {
    //My OnActionExecuting method which will be called when an Action is being executed. It can be extended to include other methods such as OnActionExecuted if required
    void OnActionExecuting(TAttribute attribute, ActionExecutingContext context);
}
```

ActionFilterDispatcher:

```
/// <summary>
/// The dispatcher(which gets added to the GlobalFilters) requires the simple injector container which contains all instances of injected classes.
/// Inherit from the MVC library IActionFilter in order to gain access to the OnActionExecuting method
/// </summary>
public class ActionFilterDispatcher : IActionFilter {
    private readonly Func<Type, IEnumerable> _container;

    public ActionFilterDispatcher(Func<Type, IEnumerable> container) {
        this._container = container;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) { }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
        var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor;
        //Get all attributes on a controller/action and cast them to the generic Attribute class
        var attributes = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .Concat(descriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true))
            .Cast<Attribute>();

        //Foreach attribute call the OnActionExecuting method for the IActionFilter of the attribute(E.g LogActionDecoraor)
        foreach (var attribute in attributes) {
            Type filterType = typeof(IActionFilter<>).MakeGenericType(attribute.GetType());
            IEnumerable filters = this._container.Invoke(filterType);

            foreach (dynamic actionFilter in filters) {
                actionFilter.OnActionExecuting((dynamic)attribute, context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LogActionDecorator:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is where the decoratee(E.g. the LogActionFilter) gets called. It is also where the implementation is contained
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TAttribute"></typeparam>
    public class LogActionDecorator<TAttribute> : IActionFilter<TAttribute> where TAttribute : Attribute {
        private readonly IActionFilter<TAttribute> _decoratee;

        public LogActionDecorator(IActionFilter<TAttribute> decoratee, IAccountManagementManager iAccountManagementManager) {
            this._decoratee = decoratee;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(TAttribute attribute, ActionExecutingContext context) {
            this._decoratee.OnActionExecuting(attribute, context);
        }
    }
```

LogActionFilter:

```
/// <summary>
/// My custom ActionFilter for the LogActionAttribute. This is the class which gets called to complete the implementation of the attribute
/// </summary>
public class LogActionFilter : IActionFilter<LogActionAttribute> {
    private readonly IAccountManagementManager _iAccountManagementManager;
    public LogActionFilter(IAccountManagementManager iAccountManagementManager) {
        _iAccountManagementManager = iAccountManagementManager;
    }
    public void OnActionExecuting(LogActionAttribute attribute, ActionExecutingContext context) {
        var fg = _iAccountManagementManager.ReturnApplicationIDAsync();
    }
}
```

LogActionAttribte:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is my custom ActionFilterAttribute. It is passive(contains no code) as the implementation will be taken care of in my LogActionFilter
/// </summary>
public class LogActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
}
```

Contoller:

```
[LogActionAttribute] 
public class AccountManagementController : Controller {

    public async Task<ActionResult> EndImpersonation() {
      //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Steven was right, I didn't understand the point of the article. Anyway, here is my updated code.